# Need to upload selected file on clicking 'Yes' in a modal confirmation box in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am new to web development and facing an issue while implementing an upload functionality. Here, what happens is on selecting a file to upload, a confirmation box appears and on clicking the'Yes' button the data gets uploaded to the server.There is no separate button for upload

I get the confirmation box on selecting the file.But not sure as to how to directly upload data to server

Component.html:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="form group">
        <label for="Upload" style="display: block;">Please select file to upload</label>
        <input type="File" id="btnUpload" name="Upload" value="Upload" (change)="Onselect($event)" style="padding-left: 450px;" #Upload />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

      <div *ngIf="filesIsSelected"
           <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">    
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to upload selected file?</p>
                <div align= center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data dismiss="modal">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="proceedUpload()">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Yes
                    </button>
                  </div>          
              </div>       
            </div>      
          </div>
        </div>
```

Component.ts:

```
Onselect(event){
debugger;
if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
          this.filesIsSelected = true;
          const files = event.target.files;
          for (let i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            const file = files[i];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => {
              this.fileToUpload.push({
                filenameWithExt: file.name,
                filename: file.name.split('.')[0],
                filetype: file.type,

              });
            };
          }
        }   
  else
      {
          this.filesIsSelected = false;
      }         
   }
   proceedUpload(){

      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('Upload Files', fileToUpload);

      this.http.post("url",  formData ).map(res => res.json())  
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))  
      .subscribe(  
      data => console.log('success'),  
      error => console.log(error)  
      )  

    }       
      }
```

proceedUpload() is the part where I need help. I am not able to figure out a way to access the files selected and upload it onto the server directly after clicking 'Yes'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should implement some function inside the "onChange" method of your file input, in a way that it prepares the image/s to be sent :

```
function prepareMyImg(event){    
     if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const files = event.target.files;
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
          const file = files[i];
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = () => {
            this.imagenes.push({
              filenameWithExt: file.name,
              filename: file.name.split('.')[0],
              filetype: file.type,
              data: reader.result.split(',')[1]
            });
          };
        }
      }
}
```

Then, when you proceedUpload(), you just add your array of image objects.

```
formData.append('Files', this.imagenes);
```

Possible working solution available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gbbje

Comment: Hi , I tried this but I get errors for 'file' and 'reader'  that they are not defined.Not sure why that happens

Comment: Try with window.FileReader(). And for files, I would like to see your HTML, perhaps there is something misplaced there

Comment: did you try avoiding camelCase in "File" input, changing its type to "file", and logging to console the "event" content?

Comment: Yes I tried that...still doesn't work.. I get this error on debugging the code. The debugger just skips the entire for loop... :-(

Comment: I think that I have just hit the problem. Try wrapping your input with the <form> tag

Comment: Hi this is the error which I get 'Cannot read property 'push' of null'

Comment: I have updated the component.ts code , according to the one you had suggested and just a little bit according to the requirement. Maybe this helps you in understanding better where exactly am I going wrong..

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I have already shared the working solution, so, here you are : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6gbbje . Choose a file, and then check how it is parsed, I am only showing the Filename now.

Comment: great! this works.... I am actually uploading excels ....can we use fileReader to get the number of rows in our excel?